# maxAttempts is not getting overridden with @StreamRetryTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-stream 3.2.2 with kafka binder and I am defining a custom retryTemplate to override the default maxAttempts (3) and disable retrying

```
  @StreamRetryTemplate
  public RetryTemplate retrier() {
    var retry = new RetryTemplate();
    retry.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(1, new HashMap<>()));
    return retry;
  }
```

But when an exception occurs in the consumer still retries 3 times instead of just 1 time

[image]

the custom retryTemplate bean doesn't get injected

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to show that your class is annotated with `@Configuration`. But it doesn't help, I can reproduce the problem. For some reason spring does not Autowire the StreamRetryTemplate map in `AbstractBinder`. Very frustrating to try and fix spring autowire effects...

Answer (score 0):

You must also specify `retry-template-name` per binding:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_retry_template

For example:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.consumer.retry-template-name=retrier
```

Comment: it didn't work, and the doc says just `If you need to be more precise with your RetryTemplate ...` NOT you must