# Spring not starting when Kafka is Offline

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, jhipster, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud messaging to connect and receive messages from Kafka, so far so good, but my application can work without Kafka if needed, Kafka is used for some events only. However, when Kafka is Offline Spring keeps trying to connect to it until it fails. What I need is for to application to start even when Kafka is off, just showing me some warning message.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: connector
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          replicationFactor: 1
          auto-create-topics: true
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        binding-in:
          destination: queue-0
          content-type: application/json
          group: connector
        binding-out:
          destination: queue-1
          content-type: application/json
          group: connector
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maxAttempts` property for every consumer:

```
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.binding-in-0.consumer.maxAttempts=1
```

More [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_common_binding_properties)

You can also define a custom retryTemplate to override the default maxAttempts (3) and disable retrying. The example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993879/maxattempts-is-not-getting-overridden-with-streamretrytemplate)